# SEO: how to index data from a client-side api requests

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, seo, angular-universal

I am not looking for a specific tutorial on how to set this up. I am actually wanting to know what is possible and what is not.

In my Angular 6 application I am learning how to load content serverside so bots can index the client data. There is a lot of data that comes from api requests that I would like to be crawled also. For example the following code gets the current pages project data from my ecommerce's API.

## In my Angular Component

```
getProductById(product_id) {
    const data = { product_id: product_id };
    return this.http.get<any>( api_url + '/getProductById', {params: data} );
}
```

this is a call to my api which returns data from BigCommerce (see below)

## my Express API

```
getProductById = (req, res, next) => {
    let product_id = req.query.product_id;
    return bc_v3.get(`/catalog/products/${product_id}`).then(data => {
        return data; // this data will then return back to the client async
    });
};
```

## is it possible to index data coming from an API?

Can the data returned from the API be indexed by SEO bots?

Comment: A quick search on youtube provides quite a few posts on what is possible with SEO and Angular. This one by one of the Angular team members is a good place to start: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fiT5g9KSxmw

Comment: I watched the whole thing. Thank you... My major question remains. "is it possible to index data coming from an API"

Comment: So you want to index raw data?

Comment: The data that comes from an API is what my users will search google for. If I’m asking the wrong question then let me know that too.

Comment: If you render your pages using angular universal, as the answer below suggests, then google will be able to index your website properly. Just add a sitemap to make sure that all your pages are discoverable

Comment: I know about angular universal I want to know about data coming from an api. All the meta descriptions images etc come from api calls

Answer (score 2):

I believe it can, if you use server side pre-rendering and inject the data into your html.  There is an example of how to do this using .Net Core here: https://github.com/MarkPieszak/aspnetcore-angular2-universal

Comment: Seems like the only way to find out if it is possible is to try but it would be too late by then. Im really looking for someone to say it can or cant be done

Answer (score 1):

There are two parts to this answer:

- **google bot**
- facebook, instagram and other **social media bots**

For **google bots** you don't need to do anything extra with angular to make google bot render all your page data. You can read these links to understand how SPA is being rendered by google bot. John Mueller created this [google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/js-sites-wg) to help developers resolve their doubts about what and how google bot works when dealing with SPA.

In a nutshell if your webmaster **fetch as google** is working properly then you don't need to worry about google bot indexing the pages. All you need is to create proper sitemaps and have title meta tags generated properly

For **social media bots** like facebook crawler you need to incorporate **angular universal** so that your pages are having appropriate preview on share. To implement social share you must use [resolve](https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve) to fetch data from backend.
For example
**routing.module.ts** should have the resolve to fetch data from backend before the component is initialized

```
        path: 'content/:id',
        component: contentDetailComponent,
        resolve: {
          content: DetailResolve
        }
```